# strangeley named drivers Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

while the drivers probably do something, I can't find much information on some of them.

in the device manager there's drivers named

- AppEx Network Accellerator LWF
- hbazqxye
- FS_Rec

are these harmful or normal?

Comment: Do you have DaemonTools installed?

Comment: no,at least not currently. I might have in the past